# SQLite and PHP displaying data from using array

Tags: php, sqlite

I wanna display columns from specific table and I did it BUT im totally new to this, and I'm trying to build this site for myself and community I have so they can redeem gear from points they get by posting. Script works fine but I wanna get rid of this stuff Array аnd arrows, you can see it on screenshot I've provided, I want to display only username and points but not whole thing.

https://gyazo.com/1cbb85765ae3fd21efa76215b7042329

here is a code that I'm using:

```
<?php
        $db = new SQLite3('phantombot.db');

        $sql = "SELECT variable, value FROM phantombot_points";

        $result = $db->query($sql);//->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

        $row = array();

        $i = 0;

         while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){

             if(!isset($res['variable'])) continue;

              $row[$i]['variable'] = $res['variable'];
              $row[$i]['value'] = $res['value'];
              $i++;

          }

          print_r($row);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the table for that

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Username</th><th>Points</th></tr>
      <?php  foreach($row as $datum): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $datum['variable'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datum['value'];?></td>
            </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: So basically all I need to do is remove last few parts of code and just paste this?

Comment: You need to paste it after the while method. Remove the `print_r($row);` and paste the answer in place of that `print_r`

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM! THANKS AGAM!

Comment: Glad i could help. Please accept if it works for you & upvote. Thanks